# Create a funcction which transform a str(binary code) in str(real words)?

Tags: python

Hi i need create a function which I put a binary and the function give me the string. Ican put a lots of words in binary and my function converts this in words reals (ASCII). i cant use list of comprehension and bitewise xor.
Something like that but no that.
Thanks for helping me

```
def binario_a_string(s):
    message = ""
    while s != "":
        i = chr(int((s[:8]), 2))
        message = message + i
        s = s[8:]
    return (message)

print(binario_a_string("00010000"))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Can you provide an example INPUT and show what OUTPUT you expect?

Comment: Or are you just asking for equivalent code that is not that inefficient and ugly?

Answer (score 0):

```
def binario_a_string(s):
    if len(s) % 8: raise Exception("Input string's length must be a multiple of 8")
    message = ""
    for i in xrange(0, len(s), 8):
        message += chr(int((s[i:i+8]), 2))
    return (message)

print(binario_a_string("010000010100001001000011"))
```

**Output**

```
ABC
```

You can use `range` functions to skip 8 indexes at a time.